# Rails: Records of two models in one collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, models, collection-select

**Part 1:** What i want is to fetch records of two tables in one collection select. Later, i want to perform search based on selected item.

So far i have managed to get the records in this manner in one select:

**Controller:**

```
@result1 = Model1.all
@result2 = Model2.all
@all = @result2 | @result1
```

**View:**

```
<%= collection_select :id,:id,@all, :id, :id,{prompt: "All Templates"} %>
```

The problem here is i want to display the name form Model1 and type from Model2.

**Part 2** If the user selects the `name`, i want to get record from Model1 and if the `type` is selected, i want to get records form Model2.

All i am able to get is the `id` of both the models in one collection select. I am out of ideas. Let me know if any more details are required. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've supplied :id to collection_select for the text_method. Check the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) to see how this helper works.

One solution would be to create an 'alias' method in each of your models which you can then call in collection_select:

model1.rb

```
class Model1
  def text_value
    name
  end
end
```

model2.rb

```
class Model2
  def text_value
    type
  end
end
```

I've named the method, text_value, for demonstration purposes. You may need to come up with a different name for that attribute.

Incidentally type as an attribute is reserved for [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) tables so it would be better to use a different attribute name.

in the view

```
<%= collection_select :id,:id, @all, :id, :text_value, {prompt: "All Templates"} %>
```

Comment: that worked like a charm man. Thanx a ton. Could you please help me figure out the part 2 of the question as well. I seem to be lost. I just have  a collection select on whose selection, the records appears. So from what i get, i have to use ajax call. So, if name is selected, the url should be of Model1 and if type is selected, the url would be Model2. How would i differentiate?

Comment: You'll need to modify where the form posts, again using a method that is more generic. It would be best if you started another question and showed more code including the view with the form code.

Comment: i'll give a try to the ideas i think will work for me first. If i don't get the results as desired, i'll sure get back here with another question and expect you to be there to help. Thanx :)